# MySQL(ActiveRecord) Counting rows where date column is on or before the grouped month and year

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, group-by

I'm currently counting user assignments created on or before a specific month in individual queries for month/year combinations over the last 12 months.  However, these are proving slower than I would like and I would like to see if there is a way to combine all of these queries into one.

This is running from a Ruby on Rails (5.0) application via ActiveRecord models connected to a MySQL database (5.6.10).

This ActiveRecord query

```rb
User.joins(:child_classrooms).where('assignments.created_at <= ?', DateTime.new(month_year[0], month_year[1]).end_of_month).count('DISTINCT users.id')
```

produces this mysql query

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT users.id) 
FROM `users` INNER JOIN `assignments` ON `assignments`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` AND `assignments`.`role_id` = 3 AND `assignments`.`assignable_type` = 'Student' 
             INNER JOIN `students` ON `students`.`id` = `assignments`.`assignable_id` 
             INNER JOIN `classrooms_students` ON `classrooms_students`.`student_id` = `students`.`id` 
             INNER JOIN `classrooms` ON `classrooms`.`id` = `classrooms_students`.`classroom_id` 
WHERE (assignments.created_at <= '2019-04-30 23:59:59')
```

The above query is produced twelve times (once for each of the past twelve months, changing the where clause timestamp) and instead I would like to have one query that returns the same data grouped by year and month, counting `assignments.created_at <=` the grouped year and month.

I'm familiar with how to group by year and month, but where I get confused is how to count only those rows where the created at timestamp is on or before the grouped year and month.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to select the year and month too, so you get one row for each of them. Then you can group by thos columns:

```
SELECT year(assignments.created_at),month(assignments.created_at),COUNT(DISTINCT users.id) 
FROM `users` INNER JOIN `assignments` ON `assignments`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` AND `assignments`.`role_id` = 3 AND `assignments`.`assignable_type` = 'Student' 
             INNER JOIN `students` ON `students`.`id` = `assignments`.`assignable_id` 
             INNER JOIN `classrooms_students` ON `classrooms_students`.`student_id` = `students`.`id` 
             INNER JOIN `classrooms` ON `classrooms`.`id` = `classrooms_students`.`classroom_id` 
WHERE (assignments.created_at <= '2019-04-30 23:59:59')
GROUP BY year(assignments.created_at),month(assignments.created_at)
```

**EDIT**
You maybe don´t need the WHERE clause

Comment: Thanks, @nacho.  This was helpful in selecting the year and month, however it looks like it's just returning the count of assignments created that month instead of the count created on and before that month.  I'm looking for a rolling total for each month.